# how to prove the hypergeometric function ${}_2F_{1}(1,1;2;-x)=\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}$

Tags: hypergeometric-function

how do I prove that $$\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}={}_2F_{1}(1,1;2;-x)$$
Here is what I tried
$$ {}_2F_{1}(1,1;2;-x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(1)_{n}(1)_{n}}{(2)_{n}}(-x)^{n}}$$
next$$(1)_{n}=n!\ \ ,\ \ \ (2)_{n}=(n+1)!  $$
$$ {}_2F_{1}(1,1;2;-x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{n!n!}{(n+1)!}(-x)^{n}}$$
$$ {}_2F_{1}(1,1;2;-x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{n!}{n+1}(-x)^{n}}$$
but
$$ \frac{\log(1+x)}{x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n+1}x^{n}}$$
Help me what did I do wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$ {}_2F_{1}(1,1;2;-x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\inf}{\frac{(1)_{n}(1)_{n}}{(2)_{n}}\frac{1}{n!}(-x)^{n}}$$

rather than your version:

$$ {}_2F_{1}(1,1;2;-x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\inf}{\frac{(1)_{n}(1)_{n}}{(2)_{n}}(-x)^{n}}$$

Comment: Thank you, I get it now, I missed that factorial

Answer (score 2):

By the definition of the hypergeometric series
$$
{_2F_1}(1,1;2;-x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(1)_n(1)_n}{(2)_n}\frac{(-x)^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(1)_n}{(2)_n}(-x)^n,
$$
since $(1)_n=n!$. Then by the definition of the Pochhammer symbol:
$$
\frac{(1)_n}{(2)_n}=n!\frac{\Gamma(2)}{\Gamma(n+2)}=\frac{n!}{(n+1)!}=\frac{1}{n+1};
$$
whence,
$$
{_2F_1}(1,1;2;-x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-x)^n}{n+1}=-\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-x)^n}{n}=\frac{1}{x}\log(1+x).
$$